# How to fill color in grid boxes randomly

Tags: java, grid, image

How can I fill color on the grid boxes randomly?

Rather than orderly as shown in picture here:

[Grid http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4ed76557de.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4ed76557de.jpg)

```
public class grid extends JPanel{
    Label one = new Label();
    Label two = new Label();
    Label three = new Label();
    Label four = new Label();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame jf=new JFrame();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.add(new YAnswers());
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    grid (){
       int rows=10; int cols=10;
       setLayout(new GridLayout(rows,cols));
       add(one); one.setBackground(Color.red);
       add(two); two.setBackground(Color.orange);
       add(three); three.setBackground(Color.green);
       add(four); four.setBackground(Color.black);
       boxes[] bx=new boxes[rows*cols];

        for(int i=0;i<rows*cols;i++){
            System.out.println("i"+i);
            bx[i]=new boxes();
            if(i%2<1)
                bx[i].setColor(1);
            add(bx[i]);
        }
    } //end grid()
}
```

Comment: @Jessy: I have edited your question to display the image directly. Do you want random colors, or do you want predefined colors in random fields?

Comment: Actually, what I mean with random is that the location of boxes that filled with color, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I edited your question before to display the image within the question. Any reason why you removed the image again and provide a link instead?

Comment: I am very sorry, I just added the label to the picture on what I mean by orderly and random.

Comment: Please check if my updated answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a random color by using `Math.random`:

```
new Color( (float)Math.random(), (float)Math.random(), (float)Math.random() );
```

BTW: Class-names start with upper-case in Java, so use `Grid` instead of `grid`.

---

**EDIT**

The following code uses [`GridBagLayout`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) to produce this result:

[alt text http://img214.imageshack.us/img214/5426/so2374295.png](http://img214.imageshack.us/img214/5426/so2374295.png)

```
public Grid ()
{
    final Color BACKGROUND = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
    final Color[] colors = new Color[]
        {Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE};

    final int ROWS=10;
    final int COLS=10;

    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    Label[][] label = new Label[ROWS][COLS];

    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gc.weightx = 1d;
    gc.weighty = 1d;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 1, 1);
    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    // fill the whole panel with labels
    for( int r=0 ; r<ROWS ; r++) {
        for( int c=0 ; c<COLS ; c++) {
            Label l = new Label();
            l.setBackground(BACKGROUND);
            gc.gridx = r;
            gc.gridy = c;
            add(l, gc);
            label[r][c] = l;
        }
    }

    // now find random fields for the colors defined in BACKGROUND
    for(Color col : colors) {
        int r, c;
        do { // make sure to find unique fields
            r = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * ROWS);
            c = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * COLS);
        } while(!label[r][c].getBackground().equals(BACKGROUND));
        label[r][c].setBackground(col);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `Color`s to a `List<Color> clut = new ArrayList<Color>()` and use one of the [`shuffle()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) methods. Another trick is to use `Queue<Color> clut = new LinkedList<Color>()` and cycle through them using `clut.add(clut.remove())` as needed.

Comment: I guess a few hundred random number generations aren't important, and the probability of @Peter Lang's solution running forever is low for reasonable ROWS and COLS selections.  Regardless, I prefer a guaranteed-completion approach like this one.  Shuffle and then iterate!

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Looking closer, I see that shuffling a `List<Point>` would preclude duplicates in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Color[]` array of the colors you want and then use a `java.util.Random` to select an index from 0 to your array length - 1.