# How to get image's coordinate on JPanel

Tags: java, image, grid, gridbaglayout, coordinate

This question is related to my previous question [How to generate Cartesian Coordinate (x,y) from GridBaglayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376027/how-to-generate-cartesian-coordinate-x-y-from-gridbaglayout)

I have successfully get the coordinate of each pictures, however when I checked the coordinate through (System.out.println) and the placement of the images on the screen, it seems to be wrong. e.g. if on the screen it was obvious that the x point of the first picture is on cell 2 which is on coordinate of 20, but the program shows x=1.

Here is part of the code:

```
public Grid (){

  setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600)); 
  ....
  setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
  GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
  gc.weightx = 1d; 
  gc.weighty = 1d;
  gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);//top, left, bottom, and right 
  gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; 

  JLabel[][] label = new JLabel[ROWS][COLS];         
  Random rand = new Random();

  // fill the panel with labels
  for (int i=0;i<IMAGES;i++){
    ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("myPics.jpg");
    int r, c;
    do{   
  //pick random cell which is empty
     r = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * ROWS);
        c = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * COLS); 
    } while (label[r][c]!=null);

    //randomly scale the images                
    int x = rand.nextInt(50)+30;
    int y = rand.nextInt(50)+30;                  
    Image image = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(x,y, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    icon.setImage(image);

    JLabel lbl = new JLabel(icon); // Instantiate GUI components 
    gc.gridx = r;
    gc.gridy = c;         
    add(lbl, gc); //add(component, constraintObj);         
    label[r][c] = lbl; 
}
```

I checked the coordinate through this code:

```
Component[] components = getComponents();     
for (Component component : components) {
   System.out.println(component.getBounds());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SwingUtilities`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) `convertPointToScreen()` and `convertPointFromScreen()` to convert between screen and component coordinates.

Addendum: Here's a simple example I used when trying to understand how components move and resize under the influence of a layout manager.

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public MyPanel() {
        super(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
            panel.add(new CenterLabel());
            this.add(panel);
        }
    }

    private static void create() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new MyPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                create();
            }
        });
    }

    private static class CenterLabel extends JLabel {

        public CenterLabel() {
            this.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            this.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            this.setOpaque(true);
            this.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160, 100));
            this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                    int w = e.getComponent().getWidth();
                    int h = e.getComponent().getHeight();
                    CenterLabel.this.setText("[" + w/2 + "\u253C" + h/2 + "]");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... in my case, I guess it about the gridbagconstraint ...I wanted the coordinate to follow the JPanel coordinate not the entire screen, so I rechecked it, I fixed it by changing gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE instead of BOTH

Answer (score 1):

> if on the screen it was obvious that
>   the x point of the first picture is on
>   cell 2 which is on coordinate of 20,
>   but the program shows x=1.

The first image will have x/y coordinates of 0/0. The second images will have coordinates of 1/0. The X/Y values of offset from 0. Is that what you are talking about?

Or is your listener added to the image not the panel in which case you need to convert the image coordinates to the panel coordinates. Check our the SwingUtilities class for methods to do this.

If you need more help post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).